# Iterate numbers Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

How to iterate simple numbers in Template Toolkit instead of iterating over hash with FOREACH?

All I could find in Documentation of TT was FOREACH.

Comment: Do you mean something like `[% FOREACH foo IN [1..10] %]`? This syntax is explained in the [List References](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be possible to build something like this:

```
[% FOREACH i IN [ 1 .. 10 ] %]
  [% i %]
[% END %]
```

See also [Template Toolkit Documentation on Variables](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References)